# How does second derivative test works?

Tags: derivatives

As first derivative is slope of tangent at given point.

Therefore second derivative should be slope of same tangent .

Then

How does second derivative works?

Comment: Do you know the relationship between the *concavity* of a function and its second derivative?

Answer (score 0):

To understand this, it is useful to view the second derivative of a function $f$ not as "the derivative of the derivative" but rather as defined by a limit $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x)-2f(x+h)+f(x+2h)}{h^2}$ which makes it easier to understand its relation to concavity/convexity, in terms of graph of function lying above/below secant lines. Thought of in this way, it is easy to understand why a critical point is a maximum if the second derivative is negative.